# Maximising function of $n$ variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, maxima-minima

I am considering the following function
$$f(x_1,\dots,x_n,y)=-\alpha \left(y-k_1\right)^2-\beta \sum_{i=1}^n\left(k_2-x_i\right)^2-\gamma \sum_{i=1}^n\left(y-x_i\right)^2 - \frac{\delta}{y-d} \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-d)\, ,$$
where $(x_1,\dots,x_n,y)\in[d,1]^{n+1}$, $d>0$ and $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$, $\delta$, $k_1$, $k_2>0$. Moreover, $x_i\leq y$ $\forall$ $i=1,\dots,$ $n$. I'm trying to calculate the maximum of this function on that domain.

Befor using "brute force" approach (i.e. by calculating derivatives, Hessian and so on), I wonder whether it's possible to obtain the absolute maximum in a more simple way. For example, I notice that $f\leq0$...

Comment: without squaring that final term, this problem is not easy

Comment: Your "brute force" method is really quite easy. You should try it before wasting a lot of time on alternatives. First hold $y$ constant. The derivatives for the $x_i$ are independent of other terms, so you can find the $x_i$ in terms of $y$ without any need for a Hessian. Then maximize for $y$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair, thank you. Then I should try to maximize $g(x_1,\dots,x_n):= f(x_1,\dots,x_n,\bar{y})$, where $\bar{y}$ is assumed as constant at moment. But why "without any need for Hessian"? I mean,  how do I know that the point that makes to zero the partial derivatives of $g$ is exactly a maximum point for $g$, without Hessian?

Comment: I was talking about finding the maximum, not proving that it was a maximum. However, I was also confusing the Jacobian (which identifies extrema) with the Hessian (which classifies the extrema when found), so the statement is not correct. However, I re-iterate that the Hessian and Jacobian here are easy to calculate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $y$ fixed as Paul Sinclair suggested. Your objective function is now separable: you can optimize each $x_i$ independently. It is also concave in $x_i$ (since the second derivative is negative), so it is maximized when the derivative is 0:
$$-2\beta (k_2-x_i) - 2\gamma(y-x_i) - \frac{\delta}{y-d} = 0$$
which can be written as
$$2(\beta + \gamma)x_i = 2\beta k_2 + 2\gamma y + \frac{\delta}{y-d}$$
so the solution is
$$x_i = \frac{\beta k_2 + \gamma y}{\beta + \gamma} + \frac{\delta}{2(\beta + \gamma)(y-d)}$$
You can plug this in and maximize over just $y$. Since the last term in your objective is not squared, maximizing over $y$ is not simple: there are probably multiple local optima. You could perform grid search for $y$, or apply a gradient based optimization algorithm and try multiple starting points.

Comment: Note that all the $x_i$ are the same at any stationary point. Plugging the expression for $x_i$ into $f$ gives a function of $y$ only that is a rational function of degree $2$. It's maxima are not hard to find.

Answer (score 1):

Are really the derivatives way the bruit force?

The derivates of 
$$f(x_1,\dots,x_n,y)=-\alpha \left(y-k_1\right)^2-\beta \sum_{i=1}^n\left(k_2-x_i\right)^2-\gamma \sum_{i=1}^n\left(y-x_i\right)^2 - \frac{\delta}{y-d} \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-d)\, $$
are zeros in the stationary points,
$$\begin{cases}
f''_{x_j}(x_1,\dots,x_n,y)=2\beta \left(k_2-x_j\right)+2\gamma \left(y-x_j\right) - \dfrac{\delta}{y-d}\, =0\\
f'_y(x_1,\dots,x_n,y)=-2\alpha \left(y-k_1\right)-2\gamma \sum\limits_{i=1}^n\left(y-x_i\right) - \dfrac{\delta}{y-d} \sum\limits_{i=1}^n (x_i-d)\, =0,
\end{cases}$$
or, for $y\not=d,$
$$\begin{cases}
2\beta (y-d)\left(k_2-x_j\right)+2\gamma (y-d) \left(y-x_j\right) - \delta\, =0, \quad j=1\dots n\\
-2\alpha (y-d)^2\left(y-k_1\right)-\gamma (y-d)^2\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\left(y-x_i\right) - \delta \sum\limits_{i=1}^n (x_i-d)\, =0,
\end{cases}$$
so
$$\begin{cases}
-2(\beta+\gamma) (y-d)x_j + 2(y-d)(\beta k_2+\gamma y) - \delta\, =0, \quad j=1\dots n\\
-2(\beta+\gamma) (y-d)\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i + 2n(y-d)(\beta k_2+\gamma y) - n\delta\, =0\\
(\gamma-\delta)(y-d)^2\sum\limits_{i=1}^nx_i + (2\alpha k_1 - \gamma y)n(y-d)^2 +n\delta d\, =0.
\end{cases}$$
Summation of the second and third equations factors $2(\gamma-\delta)(y-d)$ and $(\beta+\gamma)$ gives
$$\begin{cases}
-2(\beta+\gamma) (y-d)x_j + 2(y-d)(\beta k_2+\gamma y) - \delta\, =0, \quad j=1\dots n\\
2(\gamma-\delta)(2n(y-d)(\beta k_2+\gamma y) - n\delta) + ((2\alpha k_1 - \gamma y)n(y-d)^2 +n\delta d)(\beta-\gamma)\, =0,
\end{cases}$$
and this leads to the cubic equation for $y$ and explicit expressions for $x_j.$